# ExtJS 4.2.1. GPL Crossbrowser problems

Tags: javascript, extjs, cross-browser, extjs4.2

1.) I made my webapp centered with fixed width like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
  layout: 'anchor',
  items: [
    {
      xtype: 'mainPage',
      id: 'mainPage',
      anchor: '100% 100%',
      width: 990,
      style: 'margin:0 auto;'
    }
  ]
});
```

so, it works in Chrome, Opera and (amazing!!) in IE (at least v. 10), but does not work in Safari and Firefox (viewport still fits to the screen like with fit layout)

**question:** is this problem of framework or my? how can I solve it?

2.) All input elements by default have the same size if it placed inside the same container element, but, if it's not, size of textfield differs of size of other input elements such as  combobox, numberfield etc. (in all mentioned browsers except Firefox and ... IE10!! again, it seems Extjs developers has a "right focus" :)

actually question is the same **question:** is this problem of framework or my? how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your layout is a little weird. Using `anchor` and `width` together doesn't really make sense. Also, you didn't show what `mainPage` looks like. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: MainPage looks like rectangle 990px width and 100% height of the page. I know it's weird, but it's the only solution I found starting this app. Please, tell me how do You see it might be done.